# Configuring and installing a WCF app on Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a Web Service app.  The tools in use for this project are a Windows Server 2012 Standard and Visual Studio Pro 2013. App is in C#, .NET 4.5

At this early point in the development of this app., it's in the proof of concept stage. No database, nothing fancy at all; trying to get the basic architecture to work. Running in the development environment, everything works fine. Publishing to the server does not work. I get 404 - File or directory not found when I try to open this page in a browser. On my development system/personal web server, I can see the results of the app running on the page displayed.

I have looked at a number of tutorials and step-by-step instructions on how to do this. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280137/How-To-Deploy-a-Web-App-in-IIS) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53075/How-to-deploy-ASP-NET-Web-Application-on-server) was very helpful.

After some work on the server side, I got the web deploy feature to work from my development system to the server. I have also tried other install techniques.

I have reached a wall in narrowing down the problem because I don't know IIS architecture all that well and that seems to be the problem, unless I have misunderstood some aspect of running my test/proof of concept.   I have not gotten much help from my service provider running the server debugging this.

Any thoughts on how to narrow this problem; where to look, alternative tests to try, much appreciated.

web.config (this is the generic version generated by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Test.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8371/Design_Time_Addresses/Test/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Test.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your web.config file? Most of the errors in a deployment of wcf come from what the interface is requesting versus what is defined in the web configuration. It may also help to show one of your web service endpoints that is not working as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

adding this to the config solved the problem.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="svc-Integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```